# Sorting non-Latin strings does not work

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an issues with sorting on non-Latin strings of array object.
I have used this `_.sortBy(object, 'name')` in my code to sort on name.
Here is my array for Persian text:

```
[['id':1,'name':'ب'],['id':2,'name':'ج'],['id':3,'name':'اما']]
```

And output should be like this after sorting:

```
['id':3,'name':'اما'],['id':1,'name':'ب'],['id':2,'name':'ج']
```

But it's not giving this output. Does anyone have idea about this?

Comment: Am I the only one confused as to why one would refer to sorting strings of Persian characters specifically as _"sorting Latin"_? I'm pretty sure Persian characters are not Latin...

Answer (score 1):

First you need to correct your Array. It has an invalid format.

```
var a = [{'id':1,'name':'ب'},{'id':2,'name':'ج'},{'id':3,'name':'اما'}];

a.sort(function(a, b) {

  if (a.name > b.name) {

    return true;
  }
});
```

**Input**: `[{'id':1,'name':'ب'},{'id':2,'name':'ج'},{'id':3,'name':'اما'}]`

**Output**:  `[{'id':3,'name':'اما'},{'id':1,'name':'ب'},{'id':2,'name':'ج'}]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String#codePointAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) to get the Unicode value of a character.

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a.name.codePointAt(0) - b.name.codePointAt(0))
```

```js
var arr = [{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'ب'
}, {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'ج'
}, {
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'اما'
}];

var sortedArr = arr.sort((a, b) => a.name.codePointAt(0) - b.name.codePointAt(0));

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sortedArr, 0, 4);
```

Note that the syntax is wrong in the OP code. Use array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use the standard string function localeCompare to compare non-english strings:

```
var arr = [{'id':1,'name':'ب'},{'id':2,'name':'ج'},{'id':3,'name':'اما'}];
arr.sort(function(first, second ) {
    return first.name.localeCompare(second.name);
});
```